# R :: data.table: Generate a running balance by group using previous balance and row-wise iteration

Tags: r, data.table, iteration, row

I have following DT (data.table) in R.

```
dt <- fread("
id| rowids | charge | payment | balance
a |   1    |  7.1   |   0     |     
a |   2    |  1.2   |   3     |   
a |   3    |  1.7   |   1     |   
b |   1    |  8.1   |   0     |   
b |   2    |  2.5   |   4     |   
b |   3    |  2.3   |   2     |   
b |   4    |  3.2   |   1     |   
            ", 
            sep = "|",
            colClasses = c("character", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
"numeric"))
```

The "balance" is should be computed, within each id group, as "balance <- previous.row.balance + charge - payment", where the "previous.row.balance" is the previous row entry of "balance".

I initially underestimate the difficulty to compute the running balance. I was thinking about `dt[,previous.row.balance := (shift(balance,1),by=id]`. But R does vectorized computation. I did not have values in "balance" available for me to perform shift() since "balance" will be computed through row-by-row iteration.

I searched on StackOverflow and found a [similar question and its first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56586162/how-to-perform-multiple-row-wise-operations-with-dependency-with-previous-rows-u) greatly helped me to think through the whole process. I adapted the code in the first answer to my problem and got the following code working wonderfully to generate the running balance by group.

```
dt[rowids == 1, balance := charge, by=.(id)]
dt[rowids != 1, balance :=
    dt[,
        {
            balance1 <- balance[1L]
            .SD[rowids != 1,
                {balance1 <-  balance1 + charge - payment
                    .(balance1)
                },
                by=.(rowids)]
        },
        by=.(id)][, -1L:-2L]
]
```

Here are my questions.

1. I still cannot understand how `by=.(id)][, -1L:-2L]`, the chained brackets worked the iteration out. Since the code does not employ `shift() by = group`, I guess `[, -1L:-2L]` does the trick here to perform the iteration. But how? What does `[, -1L:-2L]` actually do here?

Sorry that I have to ask this question here, instead of commenting or asking under [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56586162/how-to-perform-multiple-row-wise-operations-with-dependency-with-previous-rows-u) . The reason is that I am brand new to StackOverflow with only 1 point of reputation. I am not allowed to comment on the original answer to that question. I also would like to vote up for that answer. Before I can do that, I have to earn more points.

2. Is there any other way, using data.table and R vectorizing computation to achieve this running balance goal, without wrapping any loop for row iteration?

Any insight or thought is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Regarding your question #2:

You can use the `cumsum` function (output matches that of the code in the question). This will take the value of `charge - payment` for the first row, then for the second the second `charge - payment` will be added to that, et cetera.

```
dt[, balance2 := cumsum(charge - payment), id]


dt
#    id rowids charge payment balance balance2
# 1:  a      1    7.1       0     7.1      7.1
# 2:  a      2    1.2       3     5.3      5.3
# 3:  a      3    1.7       1     6.0      6.0
# 4:  b      1    8.1       0     8.1      8.1
# 5:  b      2    2.5       4     6.6      6.6
# 6:  b      3    2.3       2     6.9      6.9
# 7:  b      4    3.2       1     9.1      9.1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @IceCreamToucan, for your one-line code, the simplest solution to my problem! I kept telling myself that I have to think out of the "box", i.e. the row-wise algorithm. There, the `cumsum()` is the perfect vectorized computation. I just learned from your code that I can arrange operation on vectors inside of `cumsum()` .

Comment: I ran my code and @IceCreamToucan cumsum() code on my actual working data set to compare the results. To my surprise, about 10% of entries have floating point errors between the results from these two algorithms. Although it does not matter since I have to round it to 2 decimal points for balance is in dollars, I am curious why floating point errors got involved.

Answer (score 3):

Since @IceCreamToucan has answered part 2 (how to improve the code), I'll just cover part 1 (why `x[, -1:-2]` works). From `?data.table`, we know that in general **the `j` field can be used to select columns**:

> When `j` is a vector of column names or positions to select (as in data.frame) [, then it behaves as with a data.frame].

(The words in brackets are my edit to complete the sentence.)

In particular, when `j` takes the form `n:m`, ...

- If all of n..m are negative or zero, then the specified columns are dropped
- If all of the n..m are positive or zero, then the specified columns are selected

You would also see this behavior with `j` set to `-c(1,2)` or `!c(1,2)` or `!(1:2)` or `-(1:2)`.

This behavior is based on special parsing of `j` to check for `:` or `!` or `-` being the top-level function.

Next, it is important to know that **the columns in `by=` are put as the first columns in the table**.

Combining these two points in the OP's example, you have `by=id` as the first column (the outer by) and `by=rowids` as the second column (the inner by). After these are dropped with `[, -1L:-2L]` you have the `.(balance1)` expression remaining.

Comment: Thank you @Frank for your explanation! My understanding now is, the first and second columns in `dt` are dropped. Does `-1L` drop `balance1`, which is returned from intermediate process `{...}`. Then what is the other column that `-2L` refers to in my sample code?

Comment: @JaneLu Ah, I forgot another point. I've edited it into the answer now, hope it makes sense